# Proving a polynomial has only one positive root.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $m, n, p\in \mathbb R$, $n>0, p>0$. Prove that the following equation has exactly one positive solution:

$$x^5-mx^3-nx-p=0.$$

Here is my attempt: Let $f(x)=x^5-mx^3-nx-p$, $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ and $f(0)=-p<0, \lim_{x\to +\infty} f(x)=+\infty$. This implies, there exists $\xi>0$ such that $f(\xi)=0$ as a consequence of Bolzano-Cauchy theorem.  Moreover, 
$$f'(x)=5x^4-3mx^2-n.$$
Since $(3m)^2+20n>0$ and $-5n<0$, we can easily see that $f'(x)=0$ has two roots $$x=\pm \frac{3m+\sqrt{9m^2+20n}}{10}.$$

I cannot continue to verify that $f(x)=0$ has only one positive solution?

Comment: Actually "$x^2= \frac {3m \pm \sqrt {9m^2 +20n}}{10}$" in your post.

Answer (score 9):

I think your result follows from the [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes'_rule_of_signs). The number of sign differences in your polynomial is 1, irrespective of whether $m$ is strictly positive, strictly negative or zero.

Comment: This looks like a good argument to me. Perhaps the downvoter can explain where the problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can make your method work:

$f'(x) = 0$ has exactly one positive solution
$$
 x=\sqrt{ \frac{3m+\sqrt{9m^2+20n}}{10} } \, .
$$

$f(0) = -p < 0$ and $f'(0) = -n < 0$, therefore $f$ has a local minimum
in the interval $(0, r)$ where $r$ is the smallest positive root
of $f$. So $f'(x) = 0$ for some $x \in (0, r)$.

If $f$ has another positive root $s > r$ then $f'(x) = 0$ for
some $x \in (r, s)$, in contradiction to the fact that $f'(x) = 0$
has only *one* positive solution.

Comment: Can you explain why "f(0)=−p<0 and f′(0)=−n<0, therefore ff has a local minimum in the interval (0,r)"

Comment: @Richkent: $f$ has a minimum on the interval $[0, r]$. Since $f$ is decreasing near zero, the minimum can  not be at $x = 0$. It can also not be at $x = r$, therefore it is in the interior of the interval, and then the derivative vanishes at the minimum.

Comment: @Richkent Try to visualize this explanation. Draw a rough graph.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x^5-mx^3-nx-p$.

$f(0)<0, \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$, so the IVT gives that $f$ has a positive root.

Let's call the least such root $a$, noting thus that $a^5=ma^3+na+p$

Then, for $x\ge 0, f'(x)=5x^4-3mx^2-n$.

Note that $f'(a)=5a^4-(3ma^2+n)>5a^4-3(ma^2+n)=5a^4-3(a^4-\frac{p}{a})=2a^4+\frac{3p}{a}>0$

Furthermore, for $x\ge a$, $f'(x)=5x^4-3mx^2-n\ge x^2(5a^2-3m)-n\ge a^2(5a^2-3m)-n$.

Now:

- $a^5=ma^3+na+p\implies a^2=m+\frac{n}{a^2}+\frac{p}{a^3}$
- $\implies a^2(5a^2-3m)=a^2(2m+\frac{5n}{a^2}+\frac{5p}{a^3})\ge 5n$
- $\implies f'(x)\ge5n-n=4n>0$ for $x\ge a$

So the function has a root at $a$, and increases to the right of $a$, giving uniqueness.